# Find minimum of function $\frac{\left| x-12\right| }{5}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+25}}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, absolute-value, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Find minimum of function $f(x) = \frac{\left| x-12\right|
>  }{5}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+25}}{3}$

I tried compute min using by definition of abs function.
I consider two cases:

1. when $x > 12$ we have:
   $f_{1}(x) = \frac{x-12}{5}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+25}}{3}$
   using standard method $f_{1}'(x)=0$ for $x_{0}=-15/4$ but $x_{0}$ is not in $ [12, \infty]$
2. when $x \leq 12$ we have $f_{2}(x) = \frac{-x+12}{5}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+25}}{3}$ similarly $f_{2}'(x) = 0$, and $x = 15/4$

So using observation from this method I computed minimum of
$f(15/4) = 56/15$.

Does it be a correct way?

Comment: Your method appears to be correct.

Comment: 1) can be reasoned more simply that $f_1(x)$ is strictly increasing on $x > 12$ so there can't be any minimum there.

Comment: For good measure, I would also compute the value at the boundary $x=12$ to see how it compares. To see why this is necessary, try using your method to find the minimum of the function $f(x)=|x|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use C-S and the triangle inequality:

$$\frac{|x-12|}{5}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+25}}{3}=\frac{|x-12|}{5}+\frac{\sqrt{(3^2+4^2)(x^2+5^2)}}{15}\geq$$
$$\geq \frac{|x-12|}{5}+\frac{|3x+20|}{15}=\left|\frac{12}{5}-\frac{x}{5}\right|+\left|\frac{4}{3}+\frac{x}{5}\right|\geq $$
$$\geq \left|\frac{12}{5}-\frac{x}{5}+\frac{4}{3}+\frac{x}{5}\right|=\frac{56}{15}.$$
The equality occurs for $(3,4)||(x,5)$ and $\left(\frac{12}{5}-\frac{x}{5}\right)\left(\frac{4}{3}+\frac{x}{5}\right)\geq0,$  which gives $x=\frac{15}{4},$

which says that we got a minimal value.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is spot on!

Indeed, since both terms are never negative, it is certain that there is a minimum. But you have exhibited the only possibility. It follows that that is indeed the minimum value of the function.

Comment: $\dfrac{|x-12|}5\ge0$ and $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+25}}3\ge5,$ but that does not mean the minimum of their sum is ever as low as $0+5$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I realised this, too. Thanks, though. Accordingly edited.